# QWizard/QWizardPage not displaying Logo

Tags: python, pyside6, qwizard

I want to use add an Logo to the *QWizardPage*, however nothing is displayed. I'm using PySide6.

```py
from PySide6.QtCore import Qt
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (QVBoxLayout, QApplication, QWizardPage, QWizard)
from PySide6.QtGui import (QIcon, QPixmap, QImage)

class Page1(QWizardPage):

    def __init__(self, img, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.setTitle('General Properties')
        self.setSubTitle('Enter general properties for this project.')

        # Just for testing, include the same image - this is displayed!
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        graphics = QLabel(self)
        graphics.setPixmap(QPixmap(img))
        layout.addWidget(graphics)
        self.setLayout(layout)


class ProjectWizard(QWizard):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        img = './Icon_256.png'

        self.addPage(Page1(img, self))
        self.setWindowTitle("New Project")

        # setPixmap(QWizard::WizardPixmap which, const QPixmap &pixmap)
        self.setPixmap(QWizard.LogoPixmap, QPixmap.fromImage(QImage(img)))
```

The path to the image is valid and accessible (I've included the image in the dialog as well), however, no Image is displayed. Also a change of the `which` parameter of `setPixmap(which, pixmap)` does not help. I also did not find anything helpful in the documentation of the [QWizardPage documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwizard.html#wizard-look-and-feel) page.

[image: Screenshot]

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Are you sure that the path you're using is correct as a relative one? What is the output of `print(QImage(img).isNull())`? Also note that creating a QImage to get it as a QPixmap is completely pointless, just do `QPixmap(img)`.

Comment: It returns False, as expected. Considering my example, the file loads just fine, using a QLabel with a QPixmap. However, in conjunction with my QWizardPage it does not seem to work, and to me, it looks like a bug at least in the QWizard Pyside implementation, although I did not find anything about this. Regarding the QImage: Usually I do not use this, and I've tried a few things before posting here. This is just a copy-paste relict I forgot, but thank you for that hint.

Comment: Can you try again using different values for [`setWizardStyle()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qwizard.html#wizardStyle-prop) values? Also, after setting the pixmap, is the result of `self.pixmap(QWizard.LogoPixmap).isNull()` the same?